# Can't find URL Login and Register Laravel 5.6

Tags: authentication, frameworks, laravel-5.6

I can't find login and register page when I try to access http://localhost/myproject/public/login it's not work's, but when i add index.php like this http://localhost/myproject/public/index.php/login it's work's normaly. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

On the root folder create .htaccess file and copy this file in public folder as well  and paste this code in the file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```